# Delete file from path value stored in array method fails if file is not present

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a dynamically generated array of file paths which may look like this:

```
paths = ["/lib/my_folder/foo", "/lib/my_folder/bar", "/lib/my_folder/baz", ...]
```

So I want to do:

```
for path in paths do |path|
  File.delete(path) #if file exists
end
```

This is failing as sometimes the element in the array points to a file that is no longer there.

I tried:

```
for path in paths
  if !path.blank?
    File.delete(path)
  end
end
```

but still fails with a `No such file or directory...` error msg.

How can I go about writing a loop to dele the element(s) left in the array without it failing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
paths.each { |path| File.delete(path) if File.exists?(path) }
```

Comment: Or `paths.select { |path| File.exists?(path) }.each { |path| File.delete(path) }`.